# Can cooking oil selection effect Maillard reaction?

Tags: oil, frying-pan

Ignoring flavor impartation. When pan-frying: Does picking a higher smoke point oil like avocado oil affect the speed of the Maillard reaction? Will it occur quicker if a lower smoke point oil like olive is used?

Answer (score 1):

[The Maillard reaction](https://www.scienceofcooking.com/maillard_reaction.htm) occurs at temperatures greater than 285°F (140°C). So, ignoring flavor, the oil you use (if any) has no influence over the reaction.  It needs a particular temperature to begin happening.  For *what* is happening, see the link. Now, in practice, flavor comes from both the Miallard reaction and caramelization (apart from other flavor ingredients), so the oil and the temperature can have significant impacts in that regard.